# How can I get the redirect target of a URL using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, redirect

Since [the Stack Exchange editor's image uploader doesn't like URL redirects](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279527/se-api-should-handle-302-found-on-image-upload), I'm trying to see if I can write a userscript that will do the job. Essentially, given a URL `http://foo.bar`, I need to get the final, redirected location.

`XmlHTTPRequest` and `$.ajax()` are not practical since the target sites may not permit them:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://.... No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://meta.stackexchange.com' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

Comment: Where/what is triggering the redirect?

Comment: Say you have a image uploaded on, for example, http://cubeupload.com. People who used that to embed images on SE posts used URLs like `http://i.cubeupload.com/...`, which now redirects. The image loads fine, but if you try to upload it to imgur, the uploader complains, and then you have to open the image in a new tab, get the final URL and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, because of CORS, you'll need some sort of serverside bypassing script. In PHP it would look something like this:

```
$content  = file_get_contents($_POST['url']);
foreach($http_response_header as $header) {
   if (!preg_match('/^Location:(.*)$/i', $header, $location)) {
       $location = false;
   }
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
if ($location) {
    echo '{"hasRedirection": true, "location": "'.$location[1].'"}';
} else {
    echo '{"hasRedirection": false}';
}
```

Let's call "bypass.php" to the file that holds this piece of code. By the way, its an untested code, so watch out.

Now, you can use your AJAX call to find out whether the target URL has redirection or not, simply by sending a post request to `bypass.php`, with the post field `url` that holds the target URL.

Comment: Sorry, but this needs to be done entirely client side. This is for a user script for Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Duh, i see. I can't think of any other method, sorry.